# ¿Cómo obtener los datos de un hashmap de java en mi service de Angular?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

Tengo un servicio Java que consulta a una bd (Oracle) y lo hace a través de dos filtros (fecha inicio, fecha fin) y regresa una lista con la info obtenida. Hice un método que regresa un HashMap, ya que ademas de que regresa la lista, regresa un código de error ya que puede ocurrir un error al consultar a la base, o bien puede que no haya datos con las fechas ingresadas.
es correcto mi forma de mandar el código de error cuando no haya datos? o  como debo de manejarlo?

Ahora esa lista obtenida del servicio Java con los valores la debo mostrar en una tabla en mi front (Angular) por lo cual tengo el siguiente servicio de angular, pero no se como jalar la info de mi back al front, es decir, como muestro el objeto **data** que es el que tiene la lista, o si cae en el error 400 del back que es que la lista esta vacía, como mando un msj al front diciendo que no hay datos con esas fechas, o un mensaje que diga hubo un error al consultar, como muestro la info en el front?

Java
Controller

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/consultarVal")
public class ValoresController {

    @GetMapping
    public Map<String, Object> consultarValores(
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "fechaInicio") Integer fechaInicio,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "fechaFin") Integer fechaFin) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> listValores = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            listValores = valoresService.listarValores(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in Values ");
            throw e;
        }
        return listValores;
    }

}
```

Service Java

```java
@Override
public Map<String, Object> listarValores(Integer fechaInicio, Integer fechaFin) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    List<ValoresDto> lista = new ArrayList<ValoresDto>();
    try {
        Integer inicio = fechaInicio;
        Integer fin = fechaFin;
        lista = valoresRepository.findByFechas(inicio, fin);
        if (lista.isEmpty() || lista == null) {
            LOGGER.error("No hay datos con esas fechas");
            response.put("Error", 400);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("An error ocurred");
        response.put("success", false);
        response.put("error", e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
    response.put("success", true);
    response.put("data", lista);
    return response;
}
```

Angular
Service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ValoresDto} from '../Models/ValoresDTO';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConsultarValoresService {

    Url = 'http://localhost:8080/consultarVal';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    consultarValores(fechaInicio: any, fechaFin: any) {
        return this.http.get<ValoresDTO[]>(this.Url + `?fechaInicio=${fechaInicio}&fechaFin=${fechaFin}`);
    }
}
```

Dentro de mi component tengo el método **consultarDatos()** que es el que se ejecuta cuando ingresas las dos fechas en el front, y mando a llamar al service.ts con el método **consultarValores()**, pero aquí no se como es la lógica para obtener los datos del hashmap de mi servicio Java y si cae en los casos de error como mando un msj de alerta como el que tengo ahí, ademas como lleno mi tabla con mi lista obtenida?
alguien puede ayudarme?

Component.ts

```
consultarDatos() {
    if (this.valoresForm.valid) {
        this.service.consultarValores(this.inicioFech, this.finFech).subscribe(data => {
            this.modelConsultarValores = data;
        })


    } else {
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            text: 'Debes seleccionar ambas fechas'
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: En vez de devolver un `Map`, crea un objeto que contenga la información que necesites y devuelves eso, por ejemplo.

Comment: Si quieres enviar solo el hashMap al front, siempre te va a devolver que se ejecuto correctamente, para saber si hay error tendrías que leer en el objeto de respuesta y comprebar si existe la calve error por ejemplo, aunque podrias devolver un responseEntity<?> mejor para saber si se ejecuto con exito o si hubo error

Comment: ```this.service.consultarValores(this.inicioFech, this.finFech).subscribe( d => {
            if(d.success) this.modelConsultarValores = d.data; else console.log(d.error)
        })```, asi comprobarias si se ejecuto bien en el valor del key success

Comment: @Charls entonces esta mal delvolver asi la lista y el codigo?, es que mi duda es como mandar mis alerts en el front para mostrar esos mensajes y adicional llenar mi table :/

Comment: @Root93 como mencione en el comentario de arriba, en lugar del console.log(), puedes agregar ese  valor directo en el swal, y en el text podrias colocar directamente text: d.error, asi el texto seria dinámico dependiendo del texto de error que mandes desde el back

Comment: @Charls me sale error en el succes, data y error, marca este mensaje : does not exist on type 'ValoresDto[], en esa clase solo tengo mapeado los atributos que debe regresar la lista para pintarlos en la tabla